# How to make just the color of a div go out the container

Tags: html, css

How am I able to make a div color go out of the container but still keep all of the content of the div(text, pics etc) inside of the container width?
Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: Have you tried changing the `background-color` style?

Comment: Bendy, you'll have to show us what you've done for us to help you figure out what you want to do.  Your problem you are asking about is a commonly done thing where you have a container div that's larger than your content div.  show us something

Comment: Use a second `div` or simply add `padding`.

Comment: box-shadow should do , no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing this is what you meant?

Try creating a div on the outside of the container div with the color that you have inside the div. That way the content is still contained within the div, but the color is the same throughout.

Here is a jsfiddle with 2 different options to show you what is going on. http://jsfiddle.net/rynslmns/3UQbb/1/

html:

```
<div class="color-width">
   <div class="container1">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="color-width">
   <div class="container2">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container1 {
 width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: red;
}
.container2 {
 width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: blue;
}
.color-width {
    background: blue;
}
```